# Is there a way to log all DOM method calls

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way (preferably Firefox or Chrome) to log all the DOM methods invoked/properties modified by a Web app?

I need this to understand some of the working of web apps whose code I don't have in non-minified version.

I understand that this won't give me the complete picture, but I am more interested in the web app's interaction with the browser for my purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can log all method calls for specific class of objects by wrapping all of its methods with a custom logging function:

```
var originalMethod = SomeObject.prototype.someMethod;
SomeObject.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    //log this call
    originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I've created a function that hooks up such wrappers to all (non-inherited) methods of given class and logs all calls to the console:

```
function logMethodCalls(className) {

    function wrapMethod(className, methodName, prototype) {
        var orgMethod = prototype[methodName];

        return function() {
                    window.console.debug('%c'+className+'::%c'+methodName, 'color: #FBB117; font-weight: bold', 'color: #6F4E37', {
                        details: {
                            scope: this,
                            arguments: arguments
                        }
                    });
                    return orgMethod.apply(this, arguments);
                };
    }

    if(!window[className] || typeof window[className] !== 'function') {
        window.console.error('Invalid class name.');
        return;
    }

    var prototype = window[className].prototype;

    for(var i in prototype) {
        if(prototype.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if(typeof prototype[i] === "function") {
                prototype[i] = wrapMethod(className, i, prototype);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running it like this:

```
["Document", "DocumentFragment", "Element", "Event", "HTMLElement", "HTMLDocument", "Node", "NodeList", "Window"].forEach(function(i){
    logMethodCalls(i);
});
```

You can customise the array above to track only classes that you are interested in.

The output looks like this:

[image: DevTools console output]

To be perfectly honest there is so much output that I don't think this type of debugging may be usable. You can try extending this solution even more by observing all properties (e.g. by defining [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) or [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for all objects), but this will get even more messy.

Comment: This answer does not work: `TypeError: The Document.implementation getter can only be used on instances of Document`

Answer (score 3):

Great idea! Tracking DOM changes may be useful when trying to understand how website/app works, but also while searching for performance bottlenecks ([DOM access is expensive](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas)).

I haven't found extension that does exactly what you are asking for, so I've created one. You can install DOMListener from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/domlistener/jlfdgnlpibogjanomigieemaembjeolj?hl=en&gl=PL).

[image: DOMListener console output]

DOMListener extension uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to catch all DOM changes and outputs [friendly](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#styling_console_output_with_css) messages to the DevTools console. Note that I'm using `console.debug()` so you can easily filter these messages out:

[image: DevTools console filters]

Code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/kdzwinel/DOMListenerExtension). If you prefer to avoid installing the extension or you want to get a similar output in Firefox, simply grab the [DOMListener.js](https://github.com/kdzwinel/DOMListenerExtension/blob/master/DOMListener.js) file and run it in the console.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. But I am actually looking for something more comprehensive, ones that capture all DOM methods invoked and properties being changed. Unfortunately property modifications don't generate mutation events and there are many DOM methods that don't result in DOM mods either.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you exactly mean here - you want to listen for all methods invoked and properties changed on `window.HTML*` elements? Or something more? It's should be fairly easy to do, but I don't think that output would be readable. We'll see.